# Implicit cast of generic

Tags: swift, generics

I'm working on an event class in Swift. The idea is that you can add a handler in a way that prevents retain cycles. For example:

```
let myEvent = Event<String>()
myEvent.addHandler(self, MyClass.handleMyEvent)
```

In a later step I'm adding the `+=` operator etc.

I have the following code:

```
class Event<Arg> {
  private var handlers = [EventHandler<AnyObject, Arg>]()

  func addHandler<Target: AnyObject>(_ target: Target, _ method: @escaping (Target) -> (Arg) -> Void ) {
    queue.async { [weak self] in
      guard let me = self else { return }
      let handler = EventHandler(target: target, method: method)
      me.handlers.append(handler)
    }
  }
}

struct EventHandler<Target: AnyObject, Arg> {
  weak var target: Target?
  var method: (Target) -> (Arg) -> Void
}
```

The code above doesn't compile. The Swift compiler raises the following error:

[image: compiler error]

> Cannot convert value of type 'EventHandler<Target, Arg>' to expected argument type 'EventHandler<AnyObject, _>'

The compiler doesn't seem to understand that a `(Target) -> (Arg) -> Void` can be implicitly converted to a `(AnyObject) -> (Arg) -> Void`. I can fix the code by changing the way the handler is created:

```
let handler = EventHandler(target: target, method: method as! (AnyObject) -> (Arg) -> Void)
```

But it seems weird that the explicit cast is necessary.

Any ideas? Or suggestions on how I can improve my code?

Comment: A `(Target) -> (Arg) -> Void` is *not* convertible to `(AnyObject) -> (Arg) -> Void` – a function that can only accept an instance of type `Target` (i.e a specific concrete type) cannot possibly accept *any* class instance as an argument.

Comment: @Hamish `Target` has an `AnyObject` constraint.

Comment: But `Target` is a specific concrete type. You cannot pass an `AnyObject` into something expecting a `Target`.

Comment: @Hamish It is the other way around. I'm passing `Target` into something expecting an `AnyObject`. I don't understand why that isn't allowed if I tell the compiler that a `Target` is an `AnyObject` (using the `<Target: AnyObject>` constraint)

Comment: While `Target` is a subtype of `AnyObject`, it is not true that `Generic<Target>` is a subtype of `Generic<AnyObject>`. That's the problem.

Comment: @Zyphrax, what about `let handler = EventHandler(target: target as! AnyObject, method: method)`? EDIT: never mind, I read it fully

Comment: Let us discount the fact that generics are invariant for the time being (you cannot convert an `EventHandler<T>` to an `EventHandler<U>` where `T != U`) – you would want to create a `EventHandler<AnyObject, Arg>` instance first. The problem is that you cannot convert a `(Target) -> T` to an `(AnyObject) -> T` – functions are [*contravariant* with respect to their parameter types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Function_types). A function that accepts a *single* concrete type of object cannot accept *any* object.

Comment: In the same way that you cannot possibly convert a `(String) -> Void` to an `(Any) -> Void`, even though `String` is a subtype of `Any`. If this were possible, you could call a function that accepts only a `String` argument with an `Int` argument, which would be madness.

Comment: Thanks guys, that makes sense. I guess the part that is biting me is the definition of the handlers array. Do you guys have a suggestion on how I can fix this? Perhaps I should remove the whole generic part of the EventHandler.